# Unrecognized statement near IF - usage IF with Exists

Tags: mysql

I want to update the row in table roomstatus where room_id = @id if date_in and date_out are both null. Otherwise, i need to insert new row like where room_id = @id, date_in = @dateIn, date_out = @dateIN

```
IF ((SELECT date_in FROM roomstatus WHERE room_id = @id)= NULL AND (SELECT date_out FROM roomstatus WHERE room_id = @id)= NULL ) THEN 
    UPDATE roomstatus SET date_in = @dateIN, date_out = @dateOut WHERE roomid = @id
ELSE
    INSERT INTO roomstatus (room_id,date_in,date_out) VALUES (@id,@dateIn,@dateOut)
END IF;
```

MySQL said:

```
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'IF ((SELECT date_in FROM roomstatus WHERE room_id = @id)= NULL
> AND (SELECT date_' at line 1
```

Comment: A standalone if is not valid sql..unless in a stored program(procedure,function,trigger,event) is it in a stored program?

Comment: No it is not stored program

Comment: Why does the insert in the question state date_out = @dateIN and the insert statement (...date_out) VALUES (...@dateOut)?

Comment: If you have a front end(php) you should do this there. If not I'm struggling to understand how you would attempt to do this in mysql alone since I don't see how you would build the variables to pass to the query.IN other words I don't grasp the process.

Comment: I am new in sql and try to create room management system with MySql and asp.net. I created stored procedure like you said but it gives error

Comment: DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE organize_room_id(IN dateIn DATETIME(6) , IN dateOut DATETIME(6), IN roomID INT(11))
BEGIN
 IF EXISTS (SELECT room_id FROM roomstatus WHERE room_id = roomID AND date_in = NULL AND date_out = NULL )
    THEN 
    UPDATE roomstatus SET date_in = dateIn , date_out = dateOut WHERE room_id = roomID
    ELSE
    INSERT INTO roomstatus (room_id,date_in,date_out) VALUES (roomID,dateIn,dateOut)
    END IF
END

Answer (score 0):

Some things wrong with your procedure
1) Every statement needs a terminator 2) MYSQL cannot differentiate a column name from a parameter name eg WHERE room_id = roomID - (mysql will compare the column to itself) you have to provide that info 3) the end which closes the begin needs to have the closing delimiter. The below is syntactically correct

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS P;

DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE P(IN INdateIn DATETIME(6) , IN INdateOut DATETIME(6), IN INroomID INT(11)) 
BEGIN 
    IF EXISTS (SELECT room_id FROM roomstatus WHERE room_id = INroomID AND date_in = NULL AND date_out = NULL ) THEN
     UPDATE roomstatus 
        SET date_in = INdateIn , date_out = INdateOut 
         WHERE room_id = INroomID ;
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO roomstatus (room_id,date_in,date_out) VALUES (INroomID,INdateIn,INdateOut); 
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Functionally I'm not so sure, there is no error checking to ensure that you have set the parameters to achieve what you want to do. For example you are not testing indateout so the code code may enter the update logic with indateout set to null and indatein set to a valid value - next time you call the procedure you may enter the insert logic and possibly end up with a duplicate.

Comment: First of al I appreciate for your answer.. I have one more question. When i put DELIMITER end of the procedure mysql gives an error. Why?

Comment: Worked fine for me , what else is in the mix? UI (phpmyadmin,mysqlworkbench etc)